# error in contactus form after hosting it on server

Tags: php, email, contactus

I am facing [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te6vx.png). I have created one contacts form in php via which I can receive mails from users. I uploaded it on big rock hosting. But I am getting this error which is in the image I am giving my php code in description.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; 
    $email = "abc@gmail.com" ;
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = $name+$phone;
    mail($email,$subject,$message,"From".$from);
    echo "mail sent";
    header('Location: index.php');
?>`
```

Comment: Whats the error? What is `$subject = $name+$phone;`? The from should be `From:`

Comment: click on this error in description to see the error

Comment: Is it too difficult?
https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mail()%3A+SMTP+server+response%3A+530+relaying+not+allowed

Comment: @akshay there is no specific solution found...they are giving solution on wamp server but i am asking about after hosting it on big rock...